# is it possible to fetch limited number of string from very long text column in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working with cakePHP. I have `services` table where service `name` and `details` column is present. In `details` column I have very long text for each services. So in the list of those `services` page I am showing all the `services` including `first 200` string from `details` column.
But the problem is, I am fetching all the data from `details` column but showing only `first 200 word`. So is there any way to fetch only those `first 200`  word from each `details` column by default.
This is how I am showing first 200 word from each details column.

```
<?php
   $onlyText= substr($service->details, 0, 200). ' ...';
   echo $onlyText;
   ?>
```

This is how I am fetching the data from `services` table.

`$services = $this->Services->find('all')->get()`

I had not tried anything from query side as I am not getting any way so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
$services = $this->Services
->find()
->select(['id', 'title', 'created'])
->select(['truncated_details' => 'SUBSTRING(details, 0, 200)']);

// SELECT id, AS Services_id, SUBSTRING(details, 0, 200) AS truncated_details ...
```

**Then use:**

```
foreach ($services as $service) {
   echo h($service->truncated_details);
}
```

**Other help:**

- https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#select()
- https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/text.html#truncating-text
- https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php